How to choose drives for a 6Dof manipulator with a shperical wrist
So my question I guess is tied to design or modelling(Not too sure what topic it falls under) a manipulator according to what I read in the book "Introduction to robotics:mechanics and control". So I have the following information at my disposal; the kinematics structure of my 6DoF robot,maximum arm reach, payload, all joints are revolute joints. What I am looking for is a guide(textbook with such example, reserach paper that involves this or whatever) on how to perform calculations based on the info at hand in order to choose suitable drives(motors plus reducers) for the joints. In the books I have consulted so far I have not been able to find that exactly it talks about the design quite extensively but then how do I go about doing caluations to get the torque and angular speeds for the joints so I can calculate the power from them and then I can choose suitable drives.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
